# Out of order Packet Reassembly for dnat rule using iptables

Tags: iptables, tcp, nat

We all know that packet reassembly only occurs at the destination or in between hops(when security devices need to inspect packet for threat detection or for signature macthing).

Consider a scenario where DNAT rule applied using iptables for egress interface (wireless/ethernet) of linux box to DNAT traffic to downstream server on different port.

In this case, if packets come out of order (which is normal) and the first packet is not received 1st, does the normal iptable rule cache the packets until 1st packet comes which has the layer 4 details to DNAT traffic ?
if yes, what time does it usually cache before dropping the out of ordered packets ?

Also, does it reassembles the packets and then again send them fragmented out to the server.